# how to sum values coming from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a TimesheetTable which have entires for each day(monday to friday) with EmployeeId to uniquely identify the entries of certain employee.

So when i am fetching the timesheets for a certain Employee by id i have a list of Timesheets as:

```
(
 TimesheetId(INT),
 EmployeeId(INT),
 Date(DATETIME),
 Hours(decimal),
 someotherstuff,
)
```

For each day there will be entry with hours specified.

Now i want to populate a `<table>` having columns **Month** and **Total hours**(add all the Hours from timesheet by month) of each month.
I cannot really figure out how to process this data and put it on my table.

The final table should look like:

```
Month      | Total Hours
March 2020 | 170 
April 2020 | 180
```

Comment: Which database is this on? Are you looking to use Linq for querying? In SQL, this would be a very simple `GROUP BY` aggregation exercise.

Comment: are you using Entity Framework ?

Comment: I am using SqlServer. Yes Linq will help. No i am using basic ADO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = dbContext.Timesheets.OrderBy(x => x.Date)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Date.Year, x.Date.Month })
    .Select(x => new { Year = x.Key.Year, Month = x.Key.Month, Total = x.Sum(y => y.Hours) })
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => new
    {
        MonthAndYear = new DateTime(x.Year, x.Month, 1).ToString("MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        TotalHours = x.Total
    })
    .ToList();
```